# Can anyone suggest me some papers to understand the mathematics behind the form factor

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, lattice-gauge-theory

I am trying to study semileptonic decays of $B$ mesons and different models are also there but I am not understanding how specific form factors are assigned to specific mesons. For example, right now I want to understand Lattice QCD for FCCC transition of b. What paper should I follow?